# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException, although the class exists

Tags: java

I got `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException`:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Consts/SortOfPages
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainMethod(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Consts.SortOfPages
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 6 more
```

and this is the class of SortOfPages:

```
package Consts;

public enum SortOfPages {
    POPUP("New - "),
    SILENT("Silent - ");

    public String description;

    private SortOfPages(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
}
```

in the import of the main class:

```
import Consts.SortOfPages;
```

But when I search the Const/SortOfPages, I find it, and it exists.

I try to clean, and build again - and the same.

How Can I Solve it?

Comment: post your sortofpages class code. May be you access third party library which is not including in classpath.

Comment: How do you launch your app? IDE? Command line? How did you build it? Where is the missing class? External jar? Your own jar?